# Google Service download failure in gradle

Tags: react-native, google-play-services

Followed the instructions specified in firebase cloud platform. Getting this issue while running the gradle build.

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

build.gradle , with the artifact added.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath("com.android.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Any inputs to the issue will help, checked firewall and proxy issues already.

Answer (score 1):

There are two build.gradle files in an Android Project. One is for app-level and another one is for your project root-level.
In order to setup Firebase correctly, You have to write like following in your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (build.gradle):

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin like below snippet:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

You are doing everything but in the app-level file. Try Fixing it and tell whether it worked or not.

Comment: Gradle is trying to look to download the 4.3.3 and not able to at those two locations , Not pasted the app/build.gradle here. The above gradle file is for android\build.gradle.

Thanks